# Como mostrar endpoint no maps pelo get? - javascript

Tags: javascript, ios

sou novo em programação e estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo do qual eu busco uma lista de taxis mais próximos de minha localização através de um site. Porém estou com muita dificuldade nisso.

Lista os taxistas ativos dentro de uma retângulo geográfico Endpoint:

GET https://api.99taxis.com/lastLocations

Parâmetros:

- sw: Ponto extremo sul, extremo oeste do retângulo, no formato "latitude,longitude". Ex: -23.612474,- 46.702746
- ne: Ponto extremo norte, extremo leste do retângulo, no formato "latitude,longitude". Ex: -23.589548,- 46.673392

Exemplo

Request:

GET https://api.99taxis.com/lastLocations?sw=-23.612474,-46.702746&ne=-23.589548,-46.673392

Eu consigo apenas criar um endpoint, porém não sei puxar desse service e coloca-los no mapa, por exemplo:

```
var person = MapModule.createAnnotation({

    latitude: -23.474891,
    longitude: -46.526756,
    title: 'Você',
    subtitle: 'São Paulo, SP',
    pincolor: MapModule.ANNOTATION_RED,
    image:"/ui/images/buscador.png",
});
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar com a linha de códigos para eu pegar a latidude e longitude desses taxis neste retangulo geografico??? Valeu galera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, dá uma olhada no $.getJSON() da jQuery. Eu costumo usar ele pra mexer com APIs em geral. Ele fará uma requisição com essa url e retornará um JSON com um array, onde cada índice é um ponto. Você pode percorrer esse array com um for, pasear o JSON e para casa índice pegar as chaves latitude e longitude e criar um endpoint no mapa.

Eu fiz algo parecido num codepen há uns meses, só mudei a API de onde pego as informações, mas no geral é bem o que você ta precisando. Dá uma olhada, pode te ajudar: http://codepen.io/andresampaio/pen/meeGVE

Valeu

Comment: André, acessei o seu link e me deu uma bela clareada... porém, ainda estou com dificuldade no for... você acessou o link das localizações? então, não estou conseguindo percorrer esse array com um for e pegar o índice das casas e chaves da latitude e longitude... também preciso daquele driverId mas sabendo o da localização eu já conseguirei executa-lo. Poderia me ajudar com isso?

Comment: É bem estranho, mas chequei os headers e etc e a resposta do servidor está lá, num JSON, certinho, porém quando uso alguma função, seja a `$.ajax` ou a `$.getJSON`, a resposta não vem, nem em texto e nem em JSON, não sei se é a API que ta bloqueando. Não consegui manipular nenhuma informação, apesar da resposta existir.